Adding a prop to a union type messes up the union
I want to make my own input elements behave like default <input /> in React, allowing it to be either controlled (with value) or uncontrolled (with defaultValue).
I implemented this in TypeScript and everything went smoothly until I added another prop to my component. It messed up the relationship between value, defaultValue and onChange.
Here's my implementation before adding an extra prop:
type OnChangeCallback = (newValue: string) => void;

interface Uncontrolled {
    defaultValue?: string;
    onChange?: OnChangeCallback;
}

interface Controlled {
    value: string;
    onChange: OnChangeCallback;
}

type Input = Uncontrolled | Controlled;

const input1: Input = {}; // OK

const input2: Input = {
    defaultValue: "Hello, world!",
}; // OK

const input3: Input = {
    onChange: newValue => console.log(`New value is ${newValue}`),
}; // OK

const input4: Input = {
    value: "Hello, world!",
}; // Error: Missing onChange, all good

const input5: Input = {
    value: "Hello, world!",
    onChange: newValue => console.log(`New value is ${newValue}`),
}; // OK

Then I added a prop named label, just to experiment:
type Input = (Uncontrolled | Controlled) & {
    label: string;
};

Now, TypeScript allowed for a component with value without onChange:
const why: Input = {
    label: "Oh dear",
    value: "Hello, world!",
}; // Why is this OK now?

Where did the requirement for onChange when there's value go when I just added another property?

The type union is not a union of properties, it's a union of valid values.

So why did it work before that property?

Given the type definitions:
type OnChangeCallback = (newValue: string) => void;

interface Uncontrolled {
    defaultValue?: string;
    onChange?: OnChangeCallback;
}

interface Controlled {
    value: string;
    onChange: OnChangeCallback;
}

type Input = Uncontrolled | Controlled;

It's possible to declare a variable of type Input that has a value and defaultValue property.
const Input6: Input = {
    value: "World",
    defaultValue: "Hello"
} // OK

If you wish to discriminate between the types in the union you will have to introduce another property.
type OnChangeCallback = (newValue: string) => void;

interface Uncontrolled {
    defaultValue?: string;
    onChange?: OnChangeCallback;
    INPUT_TYPE: "UNCONTROLLED";
}

interface Controlled {
    value: string;
    onChange: OnChangeCallback;
    INPUT_TYPE: "CONTROLLED";
}

type Input = Uncontrolled | Controlled;

const input1: Input = { INPUT_TYPE: "UNCONTROLLED" }; // OK

const input2: Input = {
    defaultValue: "Hello, world!",
    INPUT_TYPE: "UNCONTROLLED"
}; // OK

const input3: Input = {
    onChange: newValue => console.log(`New value is ${newValue}`),
    INPUT_TYPE: "UNCONTROLLED"
}; // OK

const input4: Input = {
    value: "Hello, world!",
    INPUT_TYPE: "CONTROLLED"
}; // Error: Property 'onChange' is missing

const input5: Input = {
    value: "Hello, world!",
    onChange: newValue => console.log(`New value is ${newValue}`),
    INPUT_TYPE: "CONTROLLED"
}; // OK

const Input6: Input = {
    value: "World",
    defaultValue: "Hello",
} // Error

const Input7: Input = {
    value: "World",
    defaultValue: "Hello",
    INPUT_TYPE: "CONTROLLED"
} // Error: 'defaultValue' does not exist in type 'Controlled'

const Input8: Input = {
    value: "World",
    defaultValue: "Hello",
    onChange: newValue => console.log(`New value is ${newValue}`),
    INPUT_TYPE: "UNCONTROLLED"
} // Error: 'value' does not exist in type 'Uncontrolled'


I'm really confused.

By the way, I found out that adding value?: never to Uncontrolled and defaultValue?: never to Controlled makes it behave like I needed. Stil confused though.
